# Is a template parameter evaluated at compile time?

Tags: c++

I know that templates are a compile-time construct but what I'm asking myself right now is: suppose I have the following function

```
void caller1() {
  function(1);
}
void caller2() {
  function(2);
}
void caller3() {
  function(3);
}

void function(int dimensions) {

  if(dimensions <= 0 || dimensions > 3)
     throw out_of_range("Wrong dims");

}
```

that check is not a big delay at runtime, but I was wondering if I could replace that function with a templated one with an "int dimensions" parameter to the template: my question is if that would be solved at compile time and generate code for all three functions called in the callers

Comment: Your question doesn't involve any template parameters, as far I can spot?!?

Comment: So the answer is No. Both Tom and Nikos answers fail to say that, even though they explained why it wouldn't work in your case.

Comment: @Spundun: What are you talking about? The answer to the OP's question is yes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But the format is such that it could be easily replaced by a templated form, which is what the user was asking about. Of course, that would require either code repetition or an auxiliary template (still with some repetition) if template specialization were used; [static asserts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) might be the best choice if C++11 or later is available and the check can be compile-time.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley : "my question is if that would be solved at compile time and generate code for all three functions called in the callers"... He wants to avoid checking the dimensions at runtime, and instead wants to pass it as a template parameter... But the dimensions is passed as an argument into the function so it's not known at compile time.

Comment: @Spundun His use of `caller1`, `caller2`, and `caller3` functions makes it seem as though the determination of dimension is indeed done at compile-time.

Comment: @Spundun: *"but I was wondering if I could replace that function with a templated one with an "int dimensions" parameter to the template"* -- In other words, he's talking about replacing his current function with a function template which looks like this: `template<int Dimensions> void function() { ... }`

Comment: Yikes I was completely off base, and read the whole thing wrong. Apologies for unnecessarily raising the temperature.

Comment: A template defines a family of functions (or classes/structs/whatever), not a single entity that behaves differently based on parameters given. What you have now (non-templated) is a single function that does different things based on the dimension value. Converting that to a template would give you a different function for every dimension it is ever called with. Whether the function then threw an exception, failed to compile, or just ended up with an empty body for the undesired cases would depend on exactly how you wrote it... There is potential for code bloat on that road...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would work, as long as the `dimensions` parameter is always known at compile-time. See http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/22/c-template-syntax-patterns/ for some descriptions of using templates in ways other than the usual "make this container flexible".

Answer (score 7):

If an expression is not compile time evaluated it can't be a template parameter.

Your construct can be modified to perform a compile time evaluation, but that wouldn't result in runtime error (exception) but a compilation error :

```
template<int N>
typename std::enable_if<(N>0 && N<=3)>::type function() {
     // stuff     
}
```

but that would require the dimensions `N` to be known at compile time, so that you'd call the function like this :

```
function<2>(); // OK
function<5>(); // compilation error
```

Comment: should be template<int N> not typename

Comment: @sam thnx for the correction (quick writing -> silly mistakes)

Comment: you could also do `template <int N> ......function(N)...` right? that way you could call it like `function(2)` like in the original code.

Comment: @Spundun Nope. The value cannot cause deduction of template parameters, only the **type** of function argument. Yes it's a literal, but it's handled at runtime

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou thanks. Now that I think about it a bit more, it makes sense. If we decided to deduce N that way, then that's like saying you can only pass literals as that argument, can't ever pass a variable in. Which wouldn't be nice.